# Multiple Custom UITableViewCells All Become Same

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, twitter

I'm working with two custom UITableViewCell subclasses. They're both designed to hold the contents of a Tweet, one specific just to Tweets with text and the other for Tweets with text and an image. I'm creating both cells programatically in the subclasses and using PureLayout for auto-layout to avoid sizing issues.

Now when the tweets in the cells initially load, everything's fine and those with images in appear as they should using the right subclass and vice versa for those without images. But when I start to scroll the cells without text suddenly appear with the UIImageViews and images within them - even though there's not an actual image for the Tweet, they're loading images off the other Tweets.

I'm not sure what's going on, I believe it's an issue where i'm loading and setting up the cells in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Although i'm also using SDWebImage to asynchronously load the images - however it works perfectly fine for the profile images with no issues on loading different images. This might be because both the TweetWithImageCell and TweetNormalCell have profile images.

Can anyone shed some light on the best method of doing this to make it work correctly?

Code is as below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"media"]) {
        if ([[[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"media"]isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            tweetMedia = [[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"media"];
        } else {
        }
    }

    if ([tweetMedia objectAtIndex:0]) {
        //Initial cell setup
        StreamPhotoTableViewCell *cell = (StreamPhotoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierPhoto];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = tweetPhotoCell;
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        }

        NSDictionary *tweetMediaFirst = [tweetMedia objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *tweetMediaUrl = [tweetMediaFirst objectForKey:@"media_url"];
        [cell updateFonts];

        cell.titleLabel.text = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        cell.userNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];
        cell.bodyLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

        [cell.tweetImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tweetMediaUrl]
                                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tweetImagePlaceholder"]];

        NSString *profileImageUrl = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
        NSString *profileImageCheck = [profileImageUrl substringFromIndex: [profileImageUrl length] - 4];
        if([profileImageCheck isEqual:@".png"])
        {
            NSString *profileShort = [profileImageUrl substringToIndex:[profileImageUrl length] - 11];
            profileImageUrlBigger =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", profileShort];
        }
        else if([profileImageCheck isEqualToString:@"jpeg"])
        {
            NSString *profileShort = [profileImageUrl substringToIndex:[profileImageUrl length] - 12];
            profileImageUrlBigger =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg", profileShort];
        }
        else if([profileImageCheck isEqualToString:@".jpg"])
        {
            NSString *profileShort = [profileImageUrl substringToIndex:[profileImageUrl length] - 11];
            profileImageUrlBigger =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", profileShort];
        }
        [cell.profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profileImageUrlBigger]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tweetImagePlaceholder"]];

        //Reply button setup/action
        [cell.replyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(replyButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.replyButton setAccessibilityHint:[[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];

        //Retweet button setup/action
        if([[tweet objectForKey:@"retweeted"]  isEqual:@0]) {
            [cell.retweetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(retweetButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.retweetButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"retweetIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.retweetButton setAccessibilityHint:[tweet objectForKey:@"id_str"]];
        }
        else {
            [cell.retweetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(retweetedButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.retweetButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"retweetedIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.retweetButton setAccessibilityHint:[tweet objectForKey:@"id_str"]];
        }

        [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        //Initial cell setup
        StreamTableViewCell *cell = (StreamTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = tweetCell;
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        }
        [cell updateFonts];

        cell.titleLabel.text = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        cell.userNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];
        cell.bodyLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

        NSString *profileImageUrl = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
        NSString *profileImageCheck = [profileImageUrl substringFromIndex: [profileImageUrl length] - 4];
        if([profileImageCheck isEqual:@".png"])
        {
            NSString *profileShort = [profileImageUrl substringToIndex:[profileImageUrl length] - 11];
            profileImageUrlBigger =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", profileShort];
        }
        else if([profileImageCheck isEqualToString:@"jpeg"])
        {
            NSString *profileShort = [profileImageUrl substringToIndex:[profileImageUrl length] - 12];
            profileImageUrlBigger =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg", profileShort];
        }
        else if([profileImageCheck isEqualToString:@".jpg"])
        {
            NSString *profileShort = [profileImageUrl substringToIndex:[profileImageUrl length] - 11];
            profileImageUrlBigger =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", profileShort];
        }
        [cell.profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profileImageUrlBigger]
                                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tweetImagePlaceholder"]];

        //Reply button setup/action
        [cell.replyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(replyButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.replyButton setAccessibilityHint:[[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];

        //Retweet button setup/action
        [cell.retweetButton setAccessibilityHint:[tweet objectForKey:@"id_str"]];
        if([[tweet objectForKey:@"retweeted"]  isEqual:@0]) {
            [cell.retweetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(retweetButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.retweetButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"retweetIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            [cell.retweetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(retweetedButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.retweetButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"retweetedIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of cell = tweetPhotoCell and cell = tweetCell? You should be alloc/init'ing new cells if cell = nil, not returning some existing cell that you are holding a reference to. Suggest simplifying this method so you can troubleshoot better.

Comment: Good point, thanks for mentioning it. I kind of left it in there when I was playing around. Still not sure about the image issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough this seemed to solve the problem:

```
if ([[[[tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"media"] objectAtIndex:0])
```

Rather than already assigning the contents of the NSDictionary *tweet and NSMutableArray *tweetMedia and deliberately accessing the main tweetsArray through indexPath of each cell.

Answer (score 0):

This condition will be true if your array have elements in it. So the else part won't execute in that case.

```
if ([tweetMedia objectAtIndex:0])
```

Comment: Why would it? It's only true for tweets in the array that have an image link? Which explains why it initially loads fine.

Comment: Yeah I've just tried adding: else if (!tweetMedia || !tweetMedia.count) for the second cell to test this and it makes no difference. I believe it's more to do with the creation/loading of the cells as the image that appears will change when you scroll past a tweet that DOES actually have an image.

Comment: You are always checking that the first object exist or not, if it exist then how that else work ?

Comment: If you look closely the tweetMedia is actually an entirely separate array within a tweet. Specific for storing all media associated with a Tweet. I'm simply selected the first image from the media array (in case there are multiple) to display as the main image.